# Ember js table <td> view

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-paper

Im develop `Ember js` project for my university, i'm use  `ember paper` i need to show **Image 01** type list , im try to put it, i don't know how to do that, please help me to fix it, you can understand this in my images

**I need like this**

**Image 01**

[image]

**My current view**

[image]

**My code part**

```
  <div class="widget-content">
            <div id="exTab1" class="container">
              <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
                  <div class="alt-table-responsive">
                      <table class="table">

                        <tbody>
                        {{#each-in filteredAlerts as |key value|}}
                          <tr>
                                                      <td class="text-center">
                            {{value.S}}
                                                      </td>
                            <td class="text-center">


                              {{value.D}}
                            </td>


                            <td class="text-center">
                              {{value.AS}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                              <p>< {{value.AP}}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                              <a {{action "toggleModal" value.E value.S value.AID}} class="btn btn-mini btn-success"
                                                                                                     role="button" disabled={{value.isOld}}>
                                Add
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        {{/each-in}}
                        </tbody>





                      </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="2a"></div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="3a"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this new table to `Image 01` as you want, I made new table tables with new format.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<td>Intel Core<br />2017-07-15-15-09:21</td>
<td>New One<br />1003</td>
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Add</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```